# Visualforce Page - Prevent onComplete With JQuery If Condition Does Not Meet

Tags: visualforce, jquery, commandbutton, oncomplete

Folks,

I have a button calling a function in JQuery and it has `onComplete` attribute. I want to check if the condition has been met or not , if not `onComplete` will not fire.

Here the condition I want to check is the value select in `apex:selectList` is an empty string. If it is empty, the `onComplete` will not fire.

Thank you so much.

JQuery

```html
<script>
    function displayMessage(){
       if ($('select[id$="dropdownList"]').val() == '') {
           $('#warning').show(); 
       } else {
           $('#waiting').show();
           $('#button').hide();
           return true;  
       }
    }
</script>
```

Visualforce Code

```html
<apex:commandbutton value="CONVERT"
                    onclick="displayMessage();"
                    action="{!updateDetail}"
                    oncomplete="CONVERT()"
                    rerender="button"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prevent the default action, as in:

```
function displayMessage(event) {
  if(...) {
    event.preventDefault(); // prevents submission of the form
  } else {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox, thank you so much for the solution! It works in this case.